# Filter by date selected by user

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a report in MS Access based off a table, one of these tables has a column full of dates. I am making a query to generate the report but it only shows for the month and year the user wants to see. As it stands it looks like this. It currently shows the data for the current month and year but i want this use selectable.

```
SELECT o.OwnerNo, o.OwnerTitle, o.OwnerInitials, o.OwnerSurname, p.PropertyNo, p.HouseNo, p.Road, p.Postcode, t.TransactionDate, t.TransactionType, t.TransactionAmount
FROM Owners AS o, Properties AS p, Transactions AS t
WHERE (((o.OwnerNo)=[p].[OwnerNo] And (o.OwnerNo)=[Please enter the Owner Number]) AND ((t.PropertyNo)=[p].[PropertyNo]))
AND ((Month([t].[TransactionDate]))=Month([Date]))
AND ((Year([t].[TransactionDate]))=Year(now))
ORDER BY t.TransactionDate DESC;
```

Comment: Do you mean "selectable" as in defining a specific date in a variable then search for columns based on that variable?

Comment: Say for example the user only wants to see entries from Jan 2015, the user would set month as 01 and year as 2015 and it would show the data. If able the user would set this via a prompt.

Comment: I don't know how you would do this in MS-Access (I use MS SQL) but I assume you can create a stored procedure with the selected date as a parameter then do a search based on that selected date with `AND ((Month([t].[TransactionDate]))=Month(@dtSelectedDate))
AND ((Year([t].[TransactionDate]))=Year(@dtSelectedDate))`

Comment: The dates are all on a column shown as t.TransactionDate if thats what you mean? I want the user inputed dates just to be used to filter.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. My previous comment should show what you needed. How is the query being called? Either way the user's inputed date will need to be stored as a variable then you can use that variable in the filter.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was for someone else but they since removed their post. The query is being ran as a query in access. When running yours it displays the user input boxes but doesn't do anything with the data, it just displays a blank result.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas then since ms-access is not my expertise :(. This would of been much easier for me to solve in ms sql lol.

Comment: What type of object are you getting the date/time value from? In the Query designer view, there should be a criteria field. If you added your date field form the transactions table, you should be able to put in the path to that forms control and grab the date from your object.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Month([Date])` with `[Enter the month number here]` and 
`Year(now)` with `[Enter the year number here]`